# Pull from table based on prefix value

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with a MYSQL statement using PHP.

I have the following tables:

```
Table: app_main
Columns: id, eid

Table: app_equipment
Columns: id, name

Table: app_locations
Columns: id, name
```

If a value stored in the 'eid' of the app_main starts table that starts with the prefix 'e_', I want the id and name to be pulled from the app_equipment table. If a value stored in the 'eid' of the app_main table and starts with the prefix 'l_', I want the id and name to be pulled from the app_locations table. I'm trying to figure out how to write one mysql statement in php to do this.

[MySql Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPzhg.jpg)

So the results would be:
Equipment 1
Location 2
Location 3

Comment: The schema in your db is very bad, you can't change it ?

Comment: @JeanDoux: This isn't necessarily an example of a very bad schema... are other alternatives possible? sure. do those alternatives fit the use cases better? not necessarily.

Comment: Updated the information

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be use two SELECTs and combine the results with a UNION ALL set operator.

The specification isn't entirely clear (example data and expected output would go a long ways towards illustrating the requirements.)

But we could do something like this:

```
SELECT ee.id
     , ee.name
  FROM app_main em 
  JOIN app_equipment ee
    ON ee.id = em.id
 WHERE em.e_id LIKE 'e\_%' ESCAPE '\\'

 UNION ALL

SELECT ll.id
     , ll.name
  FROM app_main lm
  JOIN app_location ll
    ON ll.id = lm.id
 WHERE lm.e_id LIKE 'l\_%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

That may not be the best approach. There are other alternatives to return equivalent results; but without a more defined specfication, we're just guessing what is supposed to be returned.

Note that the `UNION [ALL]` set operator requires that each of the SELECT to return the same number of columns, and the columns have the same datatypes. If the `id` and `name` column definitions in the app_equipment table differ from the app_location table, we might need to tweak the query to make it work.

Comment: I modified the SQL in the answer, so the condition in the WHERE clauses is changed from `id LIKE` to `e_id LIKE`